# Cannot Add the Scroll Bar in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have problem with scroll bars in my datagridview.
I try to set scroll bar, but it never showing.
How can i add the scroll bars in my datagridview?
This my images of datagridview, sorry i cant show the code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `ScrollBars` property, like this:

`dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;`

If it's already set correctly, check that:

```
dataGridView1.AutoSize = false;
```

Comment: i have try that code, this very helpfull, i forget to add autosize, Thx brother.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that none of the `DataGridViewColumns` have `Frozen` property set to true. Otherwise you won't get horizontal scroll bar.

`DataGridViewColumn.Frozen = false`